# gem install won't do anything - Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, ruby, rvm, gem

I just got a recent installation of Mountain Lion. I installed homebrew and the gcc on dupes to compile proper rubies. Now, with new versions of ruby (1.9.2) I can create and install gemsets and gems.

However, I also need an old environment with ree-1.8.6-20090610. In this environment, when I type `gem install whatever`, it will not do anything at all.

Here's a trace and some information you may find useful:

```
➜  dev git:(master) ✗ gem install rails -v 2.1.1 -V       
/Users/bernatrafalesimulet/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.6-20090610@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:48: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
Installing gem rake-10.0.2
➜  dev git:(master) ✗ gem list
/Users/bernatrafalesimulet/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.6-20090610@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:48: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
➜  dev git:(master) ✗ rubies

rvm rubies

=> ree-1.8.6-20090610 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

➜  dev git:(master) ✗ gemsets

gemsets for ree-1.8.6-20090610 (found in /Users/bernatrafalesimulet/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.6-20090610)
=> (default)
   global
   rails2
```

The same happens when I try to install any other gem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use ruby first:

```
rvm use ree-1.8.6-20090610
```

this is required when PATH get's modified after RVM was sourced and loaded ruby.

you can confirm that ruby is properly loaded by comparing beginning of `PATH` with `GEM_PATH`.

also make sure there are no extra settings for rubygems in `~/.gemrc`, rvm has a test for this:

```
rvm get head
```

and make sure to read the output - if there were any extra settings in `~/.gemrc` you should install all gems all over again.